# How do i remove all characters in a string Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, string-formatting, money-format, removeall

I have a form that sends money value e.g

```
<input type="text" name="amount" value="N50,000.00 NGN" />
<input type="button" value="submit">
```

I want to remove all characters in the amount field leaving only the numbers in this format;

```
<input type="text" name="amount" value="50000" />
<input type="button" value="submit">
```

what is the best method to do this with javascript?

Comment: The regex /[^0-9.]/g  will remove everything that is not a digit or decimal point.  Then you can parseInt on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first think you want to do is to strip the string or value from numbers using something like this

```
<input type="text" name="amount" value="N50,000.00 NGN" />
<input type="button" value="submit">



var amount =  $('input[name=amount]').val().replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "");
   amount=amount.replace(",", "");
   amount=parseInt(amount).toFixed(0);
```

here is a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/C69u4/

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Number('N50,000.00 NGN'.replace(/[a-z, ]/gi,''));
```

If you want only the integer part, use:

```
parseInt(Number('N50,000.00 NGN'.replace(/[a-z, ]/gi,'')),10);
```

The `replace` part removes all alphabetic characters, the comma and spaces from the string first.

Comment: That's the `parseInt` part of the answer. I suppose the amount may as well be `N50,000.34 NGN`, in that case a `Number` conversion would keep the decimals.

Comment: @ymutlu: they are modifiers. `g` stands for global (all instances), `i`  for case insensitive ('ignorecase'). See http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: I would replace with /[^0-9.]/g instead.  To cover all bases in case user inputs other symbols.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 var i = "N50,000.00 NGN";
 parseInt(i.replace(/[^\d\.]/gi, ""), 10);
```

online example : **http://jsbin.com/ojumir**

Answer (score 0):

You could try going through the string and take the characters that are digits and append them to a result string. I don't know if that's the best method, but it's one that works.

```
var res = "";
for (var c in str) { if (str[c].match(/\d/)) { res += str[c];  }  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function doWork() {
            var amount = document.getElementsByName('amount');
            var str = amount[0].value;
            var temp = '';
            for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                if (!isNaN(str[i]))
                    temp += str[i];
            }
            amount[0].value = temp;
        }
    </script>

<input type="text" name="amount" value="N50,000.00 NGN" />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="doWork();">
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your time, this actually works but with a little problem though. the result, instead of printing 50000 being (50,000)is printing 5000000 being (N5,000,000). thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function doWork() {
        var amount = document.getElementsByName('amount');
        amount[0].value = parseInt(amount[0].value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")).toFixed(0);
    }
</script>

<input type="text" name="amount" value="N50,000.00 NGN" />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="doWork();">
```